# Gulp No errors but sass is not compiling into css

Tags: json, sass, compilation, gulp, wordpress-theming

please help I'm not getting any errors but this code will not create the compiled css from the scss file. I am writing the code within the underscore WP theme if that matters I don't think it should though. I have all the dependences loaded on my machine. I will attach my JSON in the case someone would need to see that.

```
    var themename = 'taylerco';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    //prepare and optimize code
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    image = require('gulp-image'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),

   //only work with new or updated files
   newer = require('gulp-newer'),

   //name of working theme folder
   root = '../' + themename + '/',
   scss = root + 'sass/',
   js = root + 'js/',
   img = root + 'images/',
   languages = root + 'languages/';

// css via sass and autoprefixer
gulp.task('css', function(){
    return gulp.src(scss + '{style.scss,rtl.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle:'expanded',
        indentType:'tab',
        indentWidth:'1'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(postcss([
        autoprefixer('last 2 versions', '> 1%')
    ]))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(scss + 'maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(root));
});

//optimize images through gulp-image
gulp.task('images', function(){
    return gulp.src(img + 'RAW/**/*.(jpg,JPG,png)')
    .pipe(newer(img))
    .pipe(image())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(img));
});

//javascript
gulp.task('javascript', function(){
    return gulp.src([js + '*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(js));

});

//watch everything
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    browserSync.init({
        open: 'external',
        proxy: 'localhost:8888',
        port: 8080
    });
    gulp.watch([root + '**/*.css',root + '**/*.scss'], ['css']);
    gulp.watch(js + '**/*.js', ['javascript']);
    gulp.watch(img + 'RAW/**/*.(jpg,JPG,png)', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(root + '**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

//default talk (runs at initiation: gulp --verbose)
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tayler.co",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.6",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-image": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-newer": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.1",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: You could add something like gulp-tap (right after the gulp-src line) to see if your gulp.src is actually picking up any files.  Also, probably not your problem, but the gulp plogins are usually installed as devDependencies via "npm install --save-dev pluginNameHere" rather than as dependencies as you have done.  But typically if you are getting no errors or output it is because no files are being run through the pipe: your gulp.src is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a typo in your syntax.

Change

```
 return gulp.src(scss + '{style.scss,rtl.scss')
```

To

```
 return gulp.src(scss + '{style.scss,rtl.scss}')
```